# Пустая ошибка в консоле Unity 2019 на ОС Linux(Ubuntu), которая не дает запустить проект

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unity3d

у меня вот такая проблема и не знаю как её решить: Я создал новый проект в Unity Hub под версию **Unity 2019.2.1f** и при открытие пустого проекта где на сцене только камера и свет, в консоле высвечиваются пустые ошибки. С версией Unity ниже 2019 года все нормально (Unity 2017.x.x, 2018.x.x), все запускается. Как от этого избавиться? Все это работает на Linux(Ubunte 19.04). Сколько не смотрел источников в интернете, ничего не помогает.